# R simulation of correlated data

Tags: r, data.table

```
data = data.frame(GROUP = sample(1:4, size = 1000, r = TRUE),
SCORE = runif(1000),
```

HELP = runif(1000, -.2, .8))

I have sample 'data' that has variable GROUP which indicates the GROUP an individual is in and SCORE which is the SCORE for that individual and HELP which is another measure.

Now if you know that GROUP = 1 will have a higher SCORE on average  if their values of HELP are greater than 0.3, but GROUP = 2 will have a lower SCORE on average if their values of HELP are less than 0.4 how can you simulate a data set that uses this information?

Comment: @akrun do you have data.table ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an unsophisticated solution using `dplyr` to increase/decrease `SCORE` by one `sd` for the relevant conditions.

```r
library(dplyr)

sd(data$SCORE)
#> [1] 0.2868018

data <- 
   data %>% 
   mutate(helpgt3 = as.integer(HELP > .3),
          helplt4 = as.integer(HELP < .4))

original_means <- 
   data %>% 
   group_by(GROUP, helpgt3) %>% 
   summarise(mean.score = mean(SCORE))

data <- 
   data %>% 
   mutate(SCORE = case_when(
      helpgt3 == 1 & GROUP == 1 ~ SCORE + 0.2868018,
      helplt4 == 1 & GROUP == 2 ~ SCORE - 0.2868018,
      TRUE ~ SCORE
   ))

new_means <- 
   data %>% 
   group_by(GROUP, helpgt3) %>% 
   summarise(mean.score = mean(SCORE))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'GROUP' (override with `.groups` argument)

original_means
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   GROUP [4]
#>   GROUP helpgt3 mean.score
#>   <int>   <int>      <dbl>
#> 1     1       0      0.486
#> 2     1       1      0.474
#> 3     2       0      0.473
#> 4     2       1      0.525
#> 5     3       0      0.482
#> 6     3       1      0.486
#> 7     4       0      0.545
#> 8     4       1      0.521
new_means
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   GROUP [4]
#>   GROUP helpgt3 mean.score
#>   <int>   <int>      <dbl>
#> 1     1       0      0.486
#> 2     1       1      0.761
#> 3     2       0      0.186
#> 4     2       1      0.478
#> 5     3       0      0.482
#> 6     3       1      0.486
#> 7     4       0      0.545
#> 8     4       1      0.521
```

Your data

```r
set.seed(2020)
data = data.frame(GROUP = sample(1:4, size = 1000, r = TRUE),
                  SCORE = runif(1000),
                  HELP = runif(1000, -.2, .8))
```